# Why double.IsNaN has so strange implementation

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, double, ieee-754

So if decompile .net sources, you can find this code

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
[SecuritySafeCritical]
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static unsafe bool IsNaN(double d)
{
  return (ulong) (*(long*) &d & long.MaxValue) > 9218868437227405312UL;
}
```

so according to IEEE754 `NaN != NaN`

So question is simple: why it doesn't look like

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
[SecuritySafeCritical]
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static unsafe bool IsNaN(double d)
{
  return d != d;
}
```

My friend told me that implementation of `==` may be `return !IsNan(this) && this.InnerEquals(other);`

but afaik implementation of NaN is hard-coded on hardware layer, in processor itself. And we shouldn't process `NaN` case separately.

---

And one more question. Why it's so stupid?

```
bool b1 = (double.NaN == double.NaN); // false
bool b2 = double.NaN.Equals(double.NaN); //true
```

http://ideone.com/ZSRYz1

i know an implementation

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  if (!(obj is double))
    return false;
  double d = (double) obj;
  if (d == this)
    return true;
  if (double.IsNaN(d))
    return double.IsNaN(this);
  else
    return false;
}
```

but dunno WHY

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In IEEE754, a NaN value is encoded having a sign bit of `0` or `1` and an exponent section of all `1` bits. The value in the fraction section is irrelevant as long as they're not all `0` bits (if they are, it's one of the infinities rather than NaN).

Hence consider the 32-bit single precision float:

```
s eeeeeeee mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
x 11111111 ???????????????????????
```

I've used `m` (for mantissa) for the fraction bits above so as not to confuse it with the hex digit `f`.

Provided not *all* of those `?` bits are zero, it's one of the NaN encodings. If you cast that to a 32-bit long, it's a simple matter to check against binary:

```
x 11111111 00000000000000000000000
```

and, if it's larger than the positive variant or less than the negative variant , that's one of the NaN encodings.

It's the ignoring of the sign that's being done by the `&` operation since the signed `long.MaxValue` will be `2^63 - 1` (assuming it's 64-bit) so that operation will simply force the most significant bit to `0`.

The magic value is constructed from a `0` sign bit, an exponent of all `1` bits (for double precision, there are eleven of these, and all `0` bits in the fraction. Hence binary:

```
seee eeee eeee mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm
0111 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

gives `0x7ff0000000000000` or `9218868437227405312`.

Comment: Anyway i don't understand. We can compare using one assembler CMP, but here we should create a pointer, multiple with long.MaxValue, and only after it compare with hardcoded const. Is it easier and faster?

Comment: @Alex, you're not creating a pointer or multiplying, the compiler is generating code to _treat_ the address as if it's a pointer to a different type (ie, the expense is most likely at compile time, not runtime) and the operation is a simple bitwise-AND which is very efficient. Whether it's faster than `cmp` I don't know but the difference would likely be minimal.

Comment: Tnx. And one more question is added.

Answer (score 4):

Hard to be sure without being the implementor, but my guess is that the designers considered signaling NaNs (SNAN). If exceptions are unmasked then testing for equality on an SNAN will raise a hardware floating point exception.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been almost *ten years* since this question was posted, but, for what it's worth, in .NET 6 (and possibly earlier), `double.IsNaN` is implemented exactly as you suggested.

```c#
public static unsafe bool IsNaN(double d)
{
    // A NaN will never equal itself so this is an
    // easy and efficient way to check for NaN.

    #pragma warning disable CS1718
    return d != d;
    #pragma warning restore CS1718
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4822e3c3aa77eb82b2fb33c9321f923cf11ddde6/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Double.cs#L96)